# Why my reference to singleton is nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, singleton

I have this code:

In my .h file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *allInformation;
```

in m. file

I have this code...

```
+ (instancetype)sharedManager {
    static id sharedData = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedData = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedData;
}

-(void)buildJsonRequest{
    self.allInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [OpenWeatherAPI fetchData:WEATHER_DATA
                           forZipCode:[valueSelected objectForKey:@"ZipCode"]
                           andCountry:countrySelected
                           usingUnits:API_METRIC_UNITS
                          withHandler:^(NSDictionary* weatherData){

                          [[[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation] setObject:weatherData forKey:@"data"];

            }];

            [OpenWeatherAPI fetchData:FORECAST
                           forZipCode:[valueSelected objectForKey:@"ZipCode"]
                           andCountry:countrySelected
                           usingUnits:API_METRIC_UNITS
                          withHandler:^(NSDictionary* forecastData){

                          [[[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation] forecastData forKey:@"data2"];

            }];
        }
```

And when I try to retrieve my information for singleton always is nil

Another class...

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSDictionary *dataJson = [[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation];
   }
    return self;
}
```

**always dataJson is nil why??**

I would to like have a NSMutableDictionary singleton to save different request for example:

- dataJson[0] Json response (NSDictionary)
- dataJson[1] Another Json response (NSDictionary)

Comment: is [JsonParser sharedManager] nil or [[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation] nil ? post your sharedManager method.

Comment: dataJson is nill. When I try to get the information from singleton

Comment: is allInformation initialized ?

Comment: Yes if I use this code [[JsonParser sharedManager] setAllInformation:[forecastData mutableCopy]];  Works properly but when I try to save another Json Request overwrite the last one.

Comment: nsdictionary overwrites the value,  even though you called it many times  if key is same.

Comment: No, I have two calls one: [[[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation] setObject:weatherData forKey:@"data"];  And another: [[[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation] setObject:forecastData forKey:@"data2"];

Comment: Try initializing the dictionary 'allInformation' before using it.

Comment: Already have self.allInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];  but does't work,  when I try to retrieve this singleton always is nil     NSDictionary *dataJson = [[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation];

Comment: where do u call self.allInformation = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]?

Comment: ok just another comment...I see you are updating the dictionary inside a completion handler. So are you sure you are retrieving it after it got data? Try to put a NSLog inside the completion handler after setting data and see if its printing there.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri after buildJsonRequest

Comment: @Venkat Yes I put a nslog and everything its ok

Comment: and where do u call buildJsonRequest?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri in another class - (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSDictionary *dataJson = [[JsonParser sharedManager]allInformation];  }
    return self;
}

Comment: I dont see where you are calling the buildJsonRequest.  remember that fetchData is async, and you might be calling allInformation before the async call is completed which results in nil for allInformation.

Comment: Note that `[self class]` in a `shared*` singleton method is pretty much guaranteed to never be what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution =)

It's nil because never I initialized that property correctly

This is the solution

Thanks for your time and help!

I create this extra method to initialize correctly:

```
-(instancetype)init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.allInformation = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    }
    return self;
}
```

now my singleton has values stored

Comment: you said allInformation is a dictionary, but why you initialized it as array here ?

Comment: oops sorry it's my mistake let me change it

Comment: @Fabio Remove the `[self class]` from your singleton implementation.   It'll "work" until you have more than one subclass.